# Disabling Java / Enabling it only on a case by case basis

Tags: java

I seem to have Java installed on my MacBook Pro running 10.10.5. My default browser is Chrome (latest) but I also sometimes use Firefox and Safari.

As i understand in an ideal world Java would be disabled as it can pose a security risk, how can I disable it or only enable it on a case by case basis?

Comment: Do you just want to disable Java in a Browser?

Comment: Do you want to disable/enable Java based on site-by-site policy or browser-based?

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the Java plugin can be done on a browser-by-browser basis:
https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml

As macOS 10.10.5 does NOT ship with java installed, an Oracle install must have been done, you can un-install it using their docs:
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin 
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane 
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Java
```